# cakephp $uses, $this->loadModel

Tags: cakephp, controller

**What is difference between $uses and $this->loadModel()?**
CakePHPCookbook, Release 2.
page 61:
$this->loadModel(’User’, 2);
page 62: 
class RecipesController extends AppController {
public $uses = array(’Recipe’, ’User’);

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses defines which models the controller has access to by default, if you don't define this it will be the model for that controller i.e. UsersController will load User by default (and any models defined in the AppController's $uses).

loadModel will do the same however only where it is called, this is better if you only need to use the model in one action and not others.

You also have the ability to use ClassRegistry::init('Recipe')->find('all'); etc which will return a single instance of the model for single use but will not add the model to the object map.

What you should really ask yourself is why are you loading a model into a controller? Ideally you should have relationships between your models such as if you're in the Recipe controller you can call $this->Recipe and $this->Recipe->User.

I find that uses is most common from within a Shell where it has no direct access to models by default.

*Edited as per ndm's comment*

Comment: "_[...] every time a controller method is called the model will be added._" Not sure what exactly you were trying to say, but this is not correct, not even in older Cake versions. Why do I mention older Cake versions? Because as of 2.x, models are [**lazy loaded**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-0.html#models), defining `$uses` alone doesn't load anything, a model will only be loaded once you are trying to access it, see [**`Controller::__isset()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.5/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L352).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I've got this snippet in Plugin JobDirectory and it works:
class JobCategoryNamesController extends JobDirectoryAppController {
   // public $uses = array('JobDirectory.JobCategoryName');

    public function index() {
        //$this->loadModel('JobDirectory.JobCategoryName');
        $res = $this->JobCategoryName->find('all');
        $this->set('res',$res); 
    }

} 
As you can see $uses and $this->load are commented. How does it work?

Comment: Edited as per your comments ndm, I was mistaken with my initial answer. jstar by default JobCategoryNames will use JobCategoryName model and any specified in JobDirectoryAppController::$uses. If you specify $uses, you need to make sure you have JobCategoryName in the array for it to continue working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, HelloSpeakman! You make everything clear. As pointed out mr. Cornelb: ' allowing a controller to access additional models through the $uses variable, the name of the current controller’s model must also be included', but I didn't get it at once.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for [uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) and [loadmodel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel), `$uses` is an easy way to have one or more models available to the entire controller, and `loadModel` is used when you want to have access to a model that is not in the `$uses` list